# Laptop shutting down instead of sleeping when idle (W10)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, shutdown

I'm asking a question because I tried all the methods I found on the Internet.

I'm trying to fix a problem on an Asus k551ln that shuts down instead of going to sleep when left idle. I tried many methods (running troubleshooting, reinstalling fully clean windows, powercfg -restoredefaultschemes), but none of these are working.

The battery in the laptop is completely dead, meaning that when it is unplugged, the computer shuts down a few seconds after. So I tried to completely remove the battery from the computer (by opening it) and ran the computer plugged in. The problem persists; when it is idle, it shuts down instead of sleeping.

I guess it comes from a power default, but I was wondering if replacing the battery could solve the issue. Or the only thing I didn't try is to update the BIOS, could it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The battery in the laptop is completely dead, meaning that when it is
> unplugged the computer shuts down a few seconds

Your system is not working correctly because the battery is dead.

Removing the battery will not allow you to suspend (battery is needed to suspend).  Also, most systems today do not work properly without a battery installed.

Batteries DO die from use and age.

You need to replace the battery.  (Updating BIOS won't fix a dead battery).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was going to do but having a confirmation is nice !